# Proceed vs. Proceed further/ahead- Redundancy

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, expression-choice, compound-adjectives, pleonasms

In a training session on Business English, the instructor often said, **proceed and proceed further**, usually, after a pause by the speakers or whenever he interrupted.

> > Examples:
> >
> > > ```
> > >    I heard you saying something, please proceed.
> > >    Adi, you mean e-mails ?.....Oh!Ok!, please proceed further.
> > >    Please proceed further....
> > > ```

I looked up a few dictionaries and my understanding is that "further/ahead " is redundant

- Is there a broad diference between "proceed" and " proceed further"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proceed further might be a pleonasm, however in the context you gave it looks like it is being used much like `go` and `go ahead` or `go on`. As in to proceed after a pause, so shorthand for `proceed from the place at which you stopped`.